# Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled react-hook-form controller

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form

```
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import CustomSelect from "../Select/Select";
import Input from "../Input/Input";
import Button from "../Button/Button";


const Form = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    reset,
    control,
  } = useForm();

const onSubmitted = (data, e) => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(errors.Input);
    reset();
  };

return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitted)}>
        <div className="p-3">
          <label className="text-sm dark:text-gray-900">Custom Select</label>
          <Controller
            name="customSelect"
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: "This field is required" }}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <CustomSelect
                {...field}
                options={claimTypeOptions}
                placeholder="Select an option"
              />
            )}
          />
          {errors.customSelect && (
            <p className="text-red-500">This is required!</p>
          )}
        </div>
<div className="p-3">
          <Controller
            name="Input"
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: "This field is required", maxLength: 5 }}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <Input
                {...field}
                label={"Inputs"}
                type={"text"}
                placeholder={"placeholder to"}
              />
            )}
          />
          {errors.Input && errors.Input.type === "required" && (
            <span role="alert" className="text-red-500">
              This is required
            </span>
          )}
          {errors.Input && errors.Input.type === "maxLength" && (
            <span role="alert" className="text-red-500">
              Max length exceeded
            </span>
          )}
        </div>
        <Button
          type="submit"
          label={"Submit"}
          style="primary"
          customClassName="w-[135px] h-[40px]"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
```

/*customSelect component*/

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import Image from "next/image";
import Select from "react-select";
import { forwardRef } from "react";

import ArrowDown from "../../assets/arrow_down.svg";

const CustomSelect = forwardRef(
  ({ value, options, onChange, placeholder, style, onBlur }, ref) => {
    const handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
      console.log(selectedOption, "selected");
      onChange(selectedOption); // Pass the selected option to react-hook-form
    };

    return (
      <div className="relative">
        <div className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center px-2 pointer-events-none z-10">
          <Image src={ArrowDown} alt="ArrowDown" width={16} height={16} />
        </div>
        <Select
          ref={ref}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          options={options}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          isSearchable={false} // Disable text input
          isClearable={true} // Enable the clearable feature
          styles={{
            control: (provided) => ({
              ...provided,
              paddingLeft: "1.2rem", // Adjust the padding to accommodate the icon width
            }),
            indicatorSeparator: () => null, // Hide the separator line
            dropdownIndicator: () => ({
              display: "none", // Hide the dropdown indicator arrow
            }),
            menu: (provided) => ({
              ...provided,
              backgroundColor: "#E3F0FC", // Change the background color here
              zIndex: 9999, // Add a z-index to the menu
            }),
            option: (provided) => ({
              ...provided,
              fontSize: "16px", // Change the font size to 16px
              fontWeight: 400, // Change the font weight to 400 (normal)
              color: "#1A1C1E", // Change the font color to #1A1C1E
            }),
          }}
          className={`${style}`}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
);

export default CustomSelect;
```

/*Input Component*/

```
import { forwardRef } from "react";

const Input = forwardRef(
  (
    {
      label,
      type,
      value,
      disabled,
      placeholder,
      name,
      register,
      errors,
      required,
      validationSchema,
      onChange,
    },
    ref
  ) => {
    const inputStyles = {
      backgroundColor: disabled ? "#f0f4f8" : "#ffffff",
      color: disabled ? "#6b7280" : "#000000",
      borderColor: disabled ? "#e5e7eb" : "#a0aec0",
    };

    const focusStyles = {
      borderColor: "#2563eb",
      borderWidth: "2px", // Adjust the thickness as needed
    };

    return (
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        <label>
          <span className="text-sm dark:text-gray-900">{label}</span>
        </label>
        <input
          type={type}
          name={name}
          // {...register(name, validationSchema)}
          className="h-9 border rounded p-2 outline-none"
          style={{ ...inputStyles }}
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
          disabled={disabled}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          onFocus={(e) => {
            e.target.style.borderColor = focusStyles.borderColor;
            e.target.style.borderWidth = focusStyles.borderWidth;
          }}
          onBlur={(e) => {
            e.target.style.borderColor = inputStyles.borderColor;
            e.target.style.borderWidth = "1px";
          }}
          ref={ref}
        />
        {errors && errors[name]?.type === "required" && (
          <span className="error">{errors[name]?.message}</span>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
);

export default Input;
```

I've tried not using the default values in useForm. when i select a data in the customSelect component, it works fine. however when i type something in the Input component i get some errors.

**"Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component."**

And when i try to submit it, the console looks like blink submit without consoling any data. when i tried to click the submit again, the errors in the customSelect and Input component shows even if i meet the acceptable rules

Comment: What's `Input`?

Comment: Could you show `<CustomSelect />` and `<Input />` component.

Comment: Did you try to add `defaultValues` prop to `useForm` https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#defaultValues

Comment: Hi, I've already added the code for CustomSelect and Input components

Comment: Yes in my first try i've added the defaultValues in the useForm props. however im trying to make it work without the defaultValues because i' saw in some docs that defaultValues is optional

Comment: ```value={value || ''}```?

Comment: it is still happening. what i did is try the value={value || ''} and value={field.value || ''}

code for Input component:

<Controller
            name="Input"
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: "This field is required", maxLength: 5 }}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <Input
                value={value || ""}
                {...field}
                label={"Inputs"}
                type={"text"}
                placeholder={"placeholder"}
              />
            )}
          />